# antiparallel led circuit

Tags: h-bridge, led-strip

Is it possible to glow the both LEDs simultaneously in an anti-parllel circuit?

I tried with H-Bridge but I am not able to do it simultaneously. Please help me to solve this problem

[image: Antiparallel LED Circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. A bi-colour 2-pin LED can easily be switched to either colour or any blend in between with two GPIO pins. Note that only one resistor is required. Source: [2-GPIO - 1 bi-coulour, 2-pin LED](http://lednique.com/gpio-tricks/2-gpio-1-bi-colour-2-pin-led/).*

Your circuit is similar but the LEDs are in separate packages. You can get both LEDs on by switching quickly enough from one to the other so that the eye doesn't notice. 50 Hz or higher should do the trick.

- To light L1, green, switch GPIO1 high and GPIO2 low. Current will flow from left to right.
- To light L2, red, switch CPIO2 high and GPIO1 low. Current will flow from right to left.
- To cross-fade or mix colours toggle between the two states above. A smooth blend can be obtained by varying the duty cycle.
- To fade the LED switch both of the outputs either high or low for part of the time.
- To switch off the LED switch both of the outputs high or low. No current will flow and the LEDs will be dark.

See my linked article for more.

Comment: Tristate isn't needed, just the same level on both.

Comment: @Thanks, Janka! I know that and have no idea why I originally wrote it. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Flip the current direction faster than about 100 Hz (with a 50 % duty cycle) and both LEDs appear to light due to persistence of vision.